# If <li> contains specific text, return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

I have this HTML and I'm trying to return false on click if the element contains specific text.

This is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"></li>
    <li id="2"></li>
    <li id="3"></li>
    <li id="4"></li>
    <li id="5"></li>
    <li id="6">text</li>
    <li id="7"></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    var value = $(this).attr('id');
    if ("#" + value + ":contains(\"text\")"){  // Something similar to this
        return false;
    };
    alert('test');
});
```

How can I return false, if the element contains the word 'text'.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wSvLD/ (this returns false on everything)

Comment: Please don't ever use jQuery's `attr` function. It's spaghetti code. Use `this.id` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to escape those quotes in contains("text")

Or use single quotes in combination with double quotes....

Also, the value var should be inside the event function.

EDITS:

```
$("li").click(function (e) {

    var value = $(this).attr('id');

    if ( $('#' + value + ':contains("text")').length != 0 ){ 
        return false;
    }

    alert('test');

});
```

:contains returns a jQuery object, so you need to check the length of the object to see if it contains a match.

http://jsfiddle.net/8NuvP/

Comment: My bad, there was an extra paren on the if statement from your code - should work now...

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/wSvLD/ No matter the text it doesn't compile. Is your example for specific text? Because it's what I am looking for.

Comment: it alerts on every click and using > 0 is not a solution for me. I am talking about specific value which in my case is 'text'. Not characters

Comment: See edit above in my answer...im new to jsfiddle so its giving me issues...code in my answer is working as you want.

Comment: :contains returns a jquery object with all the elements matching the contains texts - so if the element does contain the text, the object will have a length of 1. http://jsfiddle.net/8NuvP/

Comment: -1 Sorry, but it makes no sense to use a selector to reselect the current DOM element, only for the purpose of searching its text content. This approach shouldn't be used.

Comment: It's not the best approach, however, it's what the OP has requested be done. He didn't ask for a better approach, he asked how to get his example working - as you can see from his comments to the other answers below. I would agree that jValdron's answer is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close!

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    if($(this).text() == "text"){
        return false;
    };
    alert('test')
});
```

Comment: This will only return false if the text equals `text`. For example, `text too` won't match.

Comment: However, according to the given example, it will work :) But you are right, if OP wants to have more text than just "text".

Comment: @jQuerybeast: jValdron's answer does exactly that. Why are you saying it doesn't work? `$(this).text() == "text"` will match the *exact word*, then return false. If the text isn't an exact match, you'll get the `alert("test")`. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/wSvLD/2/). Clicking `"text"` returns false, while clicking the others shows the alert.

Comment: If you wanted to test for the word anywhere in the content, change it to `if($(this).text().indexOf("text") !== -1) {`.

Comment: Thanks both. This is what I was looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/8NuvP/ . It's a really long JS that comes down to that where I wasn't able to not use the variable value and I tried to replace on your example 'this' with '#' + value but didn't work. Thanks though

Comment: @jQuerybeast: But honestly, it is a really bad idea to do an entire DOM selection just to reselect the same element, and search its text. I mean do whatever you want, but http://jsfiddle.net/8NuvP/1/ is a proper solution. The `:contains()` selector is meant to be used when you don't know which element to look at. In your situation, you're looking at the clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li").click(function(){
  $(this).text() == "text" ? return false: return "something else";
});
```

but if what you want to do is to use a click function on all BUT the one with "text", you should do this:

```
$('li:not(:contains("text"))').click(function(){ 
      //whatever you are trying to achieve
});
```

Comment: Hi Dbugger. I want to you use if statement cause it comes from a long chain and I want to use the "#" + value +. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('li:not(:contains(text))').click(function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: doesnt it need quotes around text?

Comment: Hi Andrew. I want to you use if statement cause it comes from a long chain and I want to use the "#" + value +. Thanks